# Matlab make new array of values without a loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

In Matlab, I don't know the best way to explain this except for an example.  Let's say I have an array called `tStart` and a `tDuration` length:

```
tStart = [3,8,15,20,25];
tDuration = 2;
```

Is there some way to get a new array such that it would be:

```
[3,4,5,8,9,10,15,16,17,20,21,22,25,26,27]
```

So what I want is to use the initial `tStart` array then make up a new array with the starting value and then next corresponding values for the length of `tDuration`.

If I do `[tStart(1:end)+tDuration]` I get an array of ending values, but how can I get the start, end, and all the values in between?

If I `[tStart(1:end):tStart(1:end)+tDuration]` I get an error.

Any help of a way to do this without a loop would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use MATLAB's implicit expansion, reshape, and the ordering of 2d arrays.

First, create a 2d array containing the desired values from `tStart`:

```
tStart = [3,8,15,20,25];
tDuration = 2;

tDurAdd = [0:tDuration].';  % numbers to add to tStart
tArray = tStart + tDurAdd;
```

This gives us

```
tArray =

    3    8   15   20   25
    4    9   16   21   26
    5   10   17   22   27
```

These are the correct values, now we just have to reshape them to a row vector:

```
tResult = reshape(tArray, 1, []);
```

The final array is:

```
tResult =

    3    4    5    8    9   10   15   16   17   20   21   22   25   26   27
```

Of course, this can all be done on one line:

```
tResult = reshape(tStart + [0:tDuration].', 1, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Let me know if this should be another question, but when using this method in Scilab it gives an error of  `Inconsistent row/column dimensions.` when trying to make tArray. Should it be the same for Scilab or will that be different? I know that `reshape` will need to be `matrix`.

Comment: @laxer I'm not that familiar with Scilab, but I gather from your error that it doesn't support implicit expansion. It also appears that it does not support the alternative in MATLAB, `bsxfun`. Sorry, but there's not much I can do for you.

Comment: It worked great in MatLab and that is what I specifically asked for, so thank you for your response. It was a lot of help!